# Framework7 how to make messages auto scroll down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-framework-7

i make a messages app that will open in modal pop  ( like login screen ).
It's work, but i have little problem. My message won't scroll down when i open it.
my chat code :

```
<div class="pages navbar-through">
  <div class="page">
     <div class="page-content login-screen-content">
       <div data-page="messages" class="page no-toolbar toolbar-fixed">
           <div class="toolbar messagebar">
               <div class="toolbar-inner"><a href="#" id="sendPhoto" class="link icon-only"><i class="icon icon-camera"></i></a>
                   <textarea placeholder="Sentuh disini"></textarea><a href="#" class="link">Kirim</a>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="page-content messages-content">
               <div class="messages"></div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

when i open it before page loaded that messages on bottom, but when im wait until page loaded that messages scroll to top
can anyone help me? thanks!

EDIT : Fixed :D Im'use this

```
$$(“.page-content”).scrollTop(10000, 400);
```

Comment: Please post a snippet of above code.

Comment: btw im use this code https://github.com/kidGodzilla/Chattr

Comment: There might be a css property "overflow:hidden" being used due to which you are not able to scroll Or try adding "overflow:auto" to the "page-content" class.

Comment: already, hm when i open it before page loaded that messages on bottom, but when im wait until page loaded that messages scroll to top

Comment: the messages are at bottom at start is because the page and the script is not loaded fully. Try to decrease your page load time or add a loader gif/image to avoid messages to show up at bottom.

Comment: Any other way? Or you have code for it

Comment: @RafiPriatnaKasbiantoro if you find the answer for your own question, you should be able to answer your question to help show the community that you are still not waiting on an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed :

> $$(“.page-content”).scrollTop(10000, 400);

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dynamic solution according to your message list size:

```
$$('.messages-content').scrollTop( $('.messages-content').get(0).scrollHeight, 400 );
```

You also may opt to use '.page-content' instead of '.messages-content'